# How to make md5sum command to show only hash value without a path in batch?

Tags: batch-file, md5sum

I have the following code to check md5sum of my images:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('md5sum U:/imagingusb/%UserInputPath%/Image/usbimage.iso') do set output=%%i
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('md5sum /dev/sdb1') do set outputusb=%%i
echo %output%
echo %outputusb%
```

The output that I get is:

```
9a4a227e872f7130652f403c568d0081 */dev/sdb1
9a4a227e872f7130652f403c568d0081 *U:/imagingusb/dfgg/Image/usbimage.iso
```

How to otput only the Hash Value without path to my ISO-image?
Just this:

```
9a4a227e872f7130652f403c568d0081 
9a4a227e872f7130652f403c568d0081
```

Comment: you can try echo %output% | awk '{print $1}'                                               and echo %outputusb% | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: Is this really bash? I thought bash variables use `$output`.

Comment: Sorry, it's batch script for Windows

Comment: Get rid of `"delims="`

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko: http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html, make an attempt yourself, as it is simpler to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `for` loops tokenize output on spaces and tabs. If you do not specify which tokens to return, you will only be able to use the first one (`for /f %%A in ("this is a string") do echo %%A` returns `this` and `echo %%B` returns `%B` instead of `is`).

To get the md5 checksum by itself, you can simply remove the `"delims="` in your code:

```
for /f %%i in ('md5sum U:/imagingusb/%UserInputPath%/Image/usbimage.iso') do set output=%%i
for /f %%i in ('md5sum /dev/sdb1') do set outputusb=%%i
echo %output%
echo %outputusb%
```

if you needed to use the paths for something else for whatever reason, you could store them in a separate token (in this example, `%%j`) like this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('md5sum U:/imagingusb/%UserInputPath%/Image/usbimage.iso') do set output=%%i
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%i in ('md5sum /dev/sdb1') do set outputusb=%%i
echo %output%
echo %outputusb%
```

Comment: thank you very much. Just deleted "delims". It works